# DI Container Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

A tag was recently created for [autofac](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autofac), which is an IoC container. The [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44170/should-a-factory-ever-be-generated-per-request) that created this tag is also correctly tagged with [dependency-injection](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency-injection).

A long, long time ago [I wanted to create a tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25038/are-there-side-effects-to-having-a-generic-ninject-factory#comment38724_25038) for [ninject](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ninject) (another IoC container) but I didn't have enough rep back then, and [dependency-injection](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency-injection) was deemed to encompass it properly. Turns out [ninject](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ninject) was also created recently, on another Ninject-specific [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36578/how-can-i-solve-my-constructor-injection-code-architecture).

While the specific IoC container chosen by the OP has zero importance as far as the *application code* is concerned (if DI is implemented correctly that is), the shape and content of an application's *composition root* (where the dependencies are resolved and the constructors are called and injected with the IoC-container-provided instances) and of its infrastructure code, is highly specific to the selected IoC container.

Therefore, I believe [dependency-injection](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency-injection) is not sufficient to properly tag a DI question that features code that is specific to an IoC container, and reviewers familiar with DI but only with certain containers might want to review [autofac](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autofac) questions but skip or ignore [ninject](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ninject) questions.

Is there a consensus that IoC container tags should be allowed to exist, or we should edit them out and simply use [dependency-injection](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency-injection)?

Comment: Can you please repeat all that in English?

Comment: @rolfl IoC => [Inversion of Control](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6551303/1188513)

Answer (score 4):

Both [autofac](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autofac) and [ninject](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ninject) currently only feature *one* question each. This supports my line of thought that DI isn't so pervasive that subdivision into different frameworks could make sense here ([dependency-injection](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency-injection) currently has 42 questions, which I take as a good omen).

Other design patterns like [mvc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mvc) have seen such widespread use that a tag for each major framework makes sense.

DI isn't there yet, so I'd support retagging and removal of the offending minor tags.

Comment: OTOH if I were to go through all 42 [dependency-injection] questions, there'd probably be a bunch that would get a [ninject] tag, and another bunch that would get an [autofac] tag, and probably another bunch that would get another IoC container's tag.

Comment: @Mat'sMug very good point, there are [8 DI questions containing “ninject”](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdependency-injection%5D+ninject) and [4 for autofac](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdependency-injection%5D+autofac)

Comment: If the policy is to remove IoC container tags until there are enough questions with those tags to show that they're widely used... I think I see a problem there